# How to give count of records in where clause

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have below code:

```
select b_id, 
       process_date
  from (select c1.b_id,
               c1.process_date,
               row_number() over(partition by a.a_id 
                                 order by c1.process_date desc) rn
          from table_a a
               inner join 
               table_b b
                 on a.a_id = b.a_id
               inner join 
               table_c c1
                 on b.b_id = c1.b_id
       ) 
 where rn = 1;
```

How to assign rn dynamically i.e rn=count(rn) .Tried and it is givng error saying that not a group by function

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use count in where clause. Use group by and having.

eg:

```
SELECT columnname, COUNT(*)   
FROM TableName
GROUP BY columnname
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use count(*) as analytic function:

```
select b_id, 
       process_date
  from (select c1.b_id,
               c1.process_date,
               row_number() over(partition by a.a_id 
                                 order by c1.process_date desc) rn,
               count(*) over()                                  cn
          from table_a a
               inner join 
               table_b b
                 on a.a_id = b.a_id
               inner join 
               table_c c1
                 on b.b_id = c1.b_id
       ) 
 where rn = cn;
```

in case you are only trying to get the last process_date its enough to sort the sub query:

```
select b_id, 
           process_date
      from (select c1.b_id,
                   c1.process_date,                   
              from table_a a
                   inner join 
                   table_b b
                     on a.a_id = b.a_id
                   inner join 
                   table_c c1
                     on b.b_id = c1.b_id
              order by c1.process_date desc
           ) 
        where rownum = 1;

 where rn = cn;
```